# How to consolidate multiple GitHub repos with dependencies?

Tags: github, dependencies

I have joined a GitHub project which has many different repositories under one user name. My task is to consolidate these repositories into more logical groupings.

Some repositories have dependencies on other repositories using hard coded paths. First, I am wondering how can I determine which repos depend on each other?

Next, what is the best procedure for bringing the files from one repo into another and then deleting the repo being moved?

Comment: If you just want to rename/move these on GitHub, you can do that right from GitHub's UI. As for dependencies, are those hard-coded paths point to GitHub repositories directly via URLs (e.g. `https://github.com/user/foo-repo`), or just as filesystem paths with same names (e.g. `foo-repo/`)?

Comment: The hard coded paths are like the first version with the full https path

Comment: I believe there are [redirects](https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here) for transferred/renamed repositories, so it might work just fine.

Comment: That link is really helpful and explains mostly what I was asking. You can submit as answer if you like.